# Count up and down from a given letter

Tags: python

I need to write a function "alphabet" that takes a string (n), and counts up and then down in the alphabet. I tried to solve it, but I could only write the code where it counts down and then up in integers. Somehow, these integers are supposed to represent a letter. I know that I should use char() and ord(), but I don't know how. Here is what I've done so far:

```
 letter= ['a''b''c''d''e''f''g''h''i''j''k''l''m''n''o''p''q''r''t''u''v''w''x''y''z']
 numbers = ['1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''10''11''12''13''14''15''16''17''18''19''20''21''22''23''24']
 index=0

   def alphabet('n')
      while index < len(letter):
        print(count[index], end=' ')
      for n in range(0,count[index]):
         print(line[index]-numbers,end='')
      print()
      index = index + 1
      for n in range(0,count[index]):
         print(line[index]+1,end='')
      print()
      index = index + numbers
```

I am aware that this is wrong, but a little guidance would be nice :)

Comment: `letter` and `numbers` both contain **one** long string, because you didn't provide any commas, so both have length *one* (Python combines consecutive string literals with nothing but whitespace in between into one). You don't need `letter` to be a list; strings can be indexed just like a list can.

Comment: You are missing the letter `s`

Answer (score 1):

I think ord() gives back the ascii code in consecutive order, for instance ord('a') gives 97 and ord('b') 98 and so on, i would work on converting one from another and adding +1 in each loop